# How can I call python program from VBA?

Tags: python, vba

Just as the title goes.

I have a python program which processes some data file I downloaded from email.

I am writing a vba script which can download the email attachments and execute the python program to process the email attachments, such that I can automate my daily job.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to turn your Python code into a COM Server and then access it like any other COM object. [This chapter from Python Programming on Win32](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565926219.do) shows how simple it can be. The rest of the chapter gets into a lot of technical details that are probably not necessary for your application. Just turn your Python code into a class, expose one method for the VBA to call it, and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shell "path to my python exe"
```

I am sorry, I haven't used python enough.
Lets say, you want to run .pyc file, it could be

```
Shell "path to python.exe argumentOfPYCFilePath"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Do you realize we need to type "python somecode.py" to make a python code run in cmd?

Comment: Yes. Make sure that Python.exe is in your path & give the full path in case of any doubts. For e.g. `c:\Python30\Python.exe someargument`