# Run Python script via VBA and give name and path of active workbook?

Tags: python, vba, excel

EDIT: This is the same question but I rewrote it, so it is more legible.

I already tried this post: [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

And this post: [Run and execute a python script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531662/run-and-execute-a-python-script-from-vba)

And this post: [How can I call python program from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963428/how-can-i-call-python-program-from-vba)

But none of the answers works for me and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Problem 1: I want to run a pythonscript from VBA excel. excel file doesn't have a home place (can be on any desktop). the code I (want to) use:

```
 Dim Ret_Val
 Ret_Val = Shell("C:\python27\python.exe \\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\DescriptionToDatabase.py")
```

The pythonfile has always the same path on the server. I cannot see wat is wrong here? All I get is a black python screen.

In the python file I call the workbook and the correct sheet:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("//10.31.13.22/SharedDocs/3 - Technical/1 - Projects/0 - Internal/RPA 138 - Engineering software/testchipdescription/upload to database/testchipdescription-template-10-11.xltm")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Database")
```

At the moment the excel workbook path is hardcoded in python. This will bring me back to problem 2: Can I pass the name and path of the excel workbook somehow to my pythonscript?

EDIT:

I tried the shell()code in command prompt.
The same as in VBA:

```
"C:\python27\python.exe \\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\DescriptionToDatabase.py"
```

It doesn't work. 'The system cannot find the path specified'.

I tried this one:

```
C:\python27\python.exe "\\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\DescriptionToDatabase.py"
```

And it works! So the cmd needs "" to handle the spaces in the path. But I can't add them in VBA because I cannot place 2 "" otherwise it errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found a solution for problem 1:

```
Dim excelToPython As String
excelToPython = """C:\python27\python.exe"" ""\\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\DescriptionToDatabase.py"""
Debug.Print excelToPython
Call Shell(excelToPython)
```

Thanks to 'Allan Browne' (https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/520558-problem-shell-space-file-name)

EDIT:

Finally I have found a workaround for problem 2. I still don't have the real solution to give the name and the path of the active workbook to my python script with the shell command.

But I write the path and name of my active workbook in a txtfile in the same folder as my python script. And then I get this information with my pythonscript et voila.. It works! Well it does what I want, but it's not a clean solution. If someone knows the correct solution, please feel free to share it :o)

my workaround solution:

code in vba-excel:

```
'via pythonscript'

Dim excelToPython As String
Dim myFileTxt As String
Dim fileTxtPath As String

'first give the name and path of active workbook to a txtfile in the same folder as ThemeColor pythonscript'

fileTxtPath = "\\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\actWBdb.txt"

myFile = FreeFile

Open fileTxtPath For Output As myFile

nameWB = ActiveWorkbook.name
pathWB = ActiveWorkbook.path

Print #myFile, nameWB
Print #myFile, pathWB

Close myFile

'run the python file'
 excelToPython = """C:\python27\python.exe"" ""\\10.31.13.22\SharedDocs\3 - Technical\13 - Reports & Templates\13 - Description\DescriptionToDatabase.py"""

Call Shell(excelToPython)
```

code in python:

```
filepath ='//10.31.13.22/SharedDocs/3 - Technical/13 - Reports & Templates/13 - Description/actWBdb.txt'
lines =  open(filepath).read().splitlines()
nameWorkbook = lines[0]
pathWorkbook = lines[1]

book = xlrd.open_workbook(pathWorkbook + '/' + nameWorkbook)
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Database")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it is possible to give the name and the path of the active excel workbook to a python script I call from this active workbook?

Yes. [You can pass argument(s) to `SHELL` function from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell), and then you would need to modify your python script to accept the argument(s) and do something with it/them.

[Python Read from Stdin with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182482/python-read-from-stdin-with-arguments)

[Python read from command line arguments or stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675938/python-read-from-command-line-arguments-or-stdin)

Comment: Thank you for these tips. I understand that my question was kind of vague, but I really look first before I asked the question. I never heard of shell. So thanks, I will look it up!

Comment: It would be easier to assist you if you actually showed your VBA code. As is, we have to guess at what you're trying to do, and since there is no `RetVal` function in VBA, I had to assume that you're using a common construct like `RetVal = Shell("some shell command")`. If you're not already using `Shell` in some way, then I have no idea what you're attempting to do, or how you're calling a python object from VBA. [Please explain further by making revision to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40657992/edit), if this doesn't solve your problem.